# htaccess rewrite with 4 query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my URLs but i'm so rusty with htaccess.

The url I must to rewrite is something like

```
http://api.example.com/endpoint.php?publicKey=VALUE1&secretKey=VALUE2&format=VALUE3&callback=VALUE4
```

Must to rewrite in

```
http://api.example.com/VALUE1/VALUE2/VALUE3/VALUE4
```

So here's what I've done with my `htaccess`file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /endpoint.php?publicKey=$1&secretKey=$2&format=$3&callback=$4 [L]
```

This isn't working as expected cause I can't read one of these variables in PHP. Even that, I can't reach the page if I don't put endpoint.php before the parameters eg: `http://api.example.com/endpoint.php/...` that's not the 
needed behavior. How I can rewrite the URLs as expected?

Comment: What Apache version do you have? Is mod_rewrite enabled? Are you allowed to use htaccess files (AllowOverride) at all?

Comment: How are you reading these parameters? If you need to put `/endpoint.php/` before the parameters for it to do anything then it would seem the above directive is not being processed at all? Do you mean like `/endpoint.php/VALUE1/VALUE2/VALUE3/VALUE4`? In this case `/VALUE1/VALUE2/VALUE3/VALUE4` is _additional pathname information_, not a query string?

Comment: @MrWhite Sorry i've said it wrong. the values will be passed to the php script as variables so I can read the `publicKey`,`secretKey`,`format` and `callback`

Comment: Which one of the variables can't you read in PHP? You are presumably reading this via the `$_GET` superglobal? Is the variable not set or just empty? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? Can you clarify that mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` is being processed? Can you clarify: "I can't reach the page if I don't put endpoint.php before the parameters", so trying to request `http://api.example.com/VALUE1/VALUE2/VALUE3/VALUE4` doesn't actually work at all?